# How to create candlestick chart with data that came from yahoo finance?

Tags: python, plotly, yfinance

I'm using `yfinance` and `plotly` libraries (python 2.7) to get **Euro/USD** data, and then create a **candlestick chart**.

This is my code to download data from yahoo finance:

```py
import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='1d', interval='30m')
```

sample output:

```
data.tail(10)


                               Open         High    Low Close   Adj Close     Volume
                 Datetime                       
2022-02-25 17:30:00+00:00   1.125239    1.125239    1.124101    1.124354    1.124354    0
2022-02-25 18:00:00+00:00   1.124480    1.125873    1.124480    1.125492    1.125492    0
2022-02-25 18:30:00+00:00   1.125619    1.126507    1.125619    1.126126    1.126126    0
2022-02-25 19:00:00+00:00   1.125999    1.126507    1.125492    1.126253    1.126253    0
2022-02-25 19:30:00+00:00   1.126634    1.126888    1.125366    1.126634    1.126634    0
2022-02-25 20:00:00+00:00   1.126888    1.127015    1.126126    1.126634    1.126634    0
2022-02-25 20:30:00+00:00   1.126507    1.127650    1.126507    1.127015    1.127015    0
2022-02-25 21:00:00+00:00   1.127142    1.127523    1.126761    1.127523    1.127523    0
2022-02-25 21:30:00+00:00   1.127650    1.127777    1.127396    1.127777    1.127777    0
2022-02-25 22:00:00+00:00   1.127142    1.127142    1.127142    1.127142    1.127142    0
```

My goal is to plot a `candlestick` style chart, I tried this code in order to create a chart:

```py
date_time = data.select_dtypes(['datetime64'])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=date_time,
                                     open=data['Open'],
                                     high=data['High'],
                                     low=data['Low'],
                                     close=data['Close'])])

fig.show()
```

The popup window showing nothing(a blank window):

[image: Resulting figure]

What am I doing wrong? and how can I do this?

Comment: Please disable `date_time = data.index.select_dtypes(['datetime64'])` and set x=data.index.

Comment: `import yfinance as yfinance` Isn't beneficial! Traditional calling for `yfinance` is `import yfinance as yf`. if you want to call it with the origin name, you can just `import yfinance`.

Comment: Yes you are right Shayan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per @r-beginners comment.  `data.index.select_dtypes(['datetime64'])` there are no columns of type date time.  You want to use the index values for xaxis, hence whole line is not needed and just use index for xaxis.

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='1d', interval='30m')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=data.index,
                                     open=data['Open'],
                                     high=data['High'],
                                     low=data['Low'],
                                     close=data['Close'])])

fig.show()
```